# JS onClick not working after append

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have some code that appends a new DIV upon the success of an AJAX request. The appended div contains a link with an onclick. However it doesn't work.

Code for appended link:

```
<span class="boldheading_smaller" id="readreplytxt_'+ msgid +'" onclick="readoffer('+ msgid +')">Read More...</span>')
```

This is the code that is used to do the append itself - its this onclick that doesn't work on the newly created div. I can't figure out why!

EDIT: The result of the append itself is correct, i.e. `onclick="readoffer('+ msgid +')"` displays as `onclick="readoffer(29)"`

Edit: Enitre function

```
function respondoffer(a, b, c) {
    var msgid = a;
    var usrid = b;
    var resp = c;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '_process/offerrespond.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            msgid: msgid,
            usrid: usrid,
            resp: resp
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#" + msgid).slideUp();
            $('<div class="offer_box" id="' + msgid + '">')
                .prepend('<img src="_img/user_images/' + usrid + '.jpg" alt="' + data.pro_name + '" class="offerimg"/>',
                '<span class="regulartext">Offer Recivied On: ' + data.date_sent + '</span><span class="regulartext" onclick="deleteoffer(' + msgid + ',' + usrid + ');" style="float: right;">Remove</span><br />',
                '<h4 class="boldheading_smaller">' + data.pro_name + '</h4><br /><br />',
                '<span class="boldheading_smaller">Offer ' + data.accept_decline + '</span>',
                '<div id="offer_details_' + msgid + '" style="margin-top: 10px; display: none;"><div style="width: 140px; float: left; margin-left: 10px;"><h4 style="display: inline; font-size: 11px; color: #333337; font-family: Verdana;">My</h4><h4 style="display: inline; font-weight: normal; font-size: 11px; color: #333337; font-family: Verdana;">Offer</h4><br /><p style="padding-left: 5px; margin: 0px;" class="smalltext_para">Food: </p><img src="_img/profile/' + data.food + '.png" /><br /><p style="padding-left: 5px; margin: 0px;" class="smalltext_para">Drinks: </p><img src="_img/profile/' + data.drink + '.png" /><br /><p style="padding-left: 5px; margin: 0px;" class="smalltext_para">Accommodation: </p><img src="_img/profile/' + data.accommodation + '.png" /><br /><p style="padding-left: 5px; margin: 0px;" class="smalltext_para">Travel Expenses: </p><img src="_img/profile/' + data.travel + '.png" /><br style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 2px;"/><p style="padding-left: 5px; margin: 0px;" class="smalltext_para">Extra Fee: </p><p style="margin: 0px; font-size: 11px; color: #333337; font-family: Verdana; font-weight: bold; display: inline;">' + data.currency + '' + data.fee + '</p></div><div style="width: 190px; float: right;"><h4 style="display: inline; font-size: 11px; color: #333337; font-family: Verdana;">Event</h4><h4 style="display: inline; font-weight: normal; font-size: 11px; color: #333337; font-family: Verdana;">Details</h4><br style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 2px;"/><p style="line-height: 2px; padding-left: 5px; margin: 0px;" class="smalltext_para">' + data.venue_name + '</p><br /><p style="padding-left: 5px; margin: 0px;" class="smalltext_para">' + data.venue_ad1 + '</p><br /><p style="padding-left: 5px; margin: 0px;" class="smalltext_para">' + data.venue_ad2 + '</p><br /><p style="padding-left: 5px; margin: 0px;" class="smalltext_para">' + data.venue_county + '</p><br /><p style="padding-left: 5px; margin: 0px;" class="smalltext_para">' + data.venue_country + '</p><br /><p style="padding-left: 5px; margin: 0px;" class="smalltext_para">' + data.venue_zip + '</p><br /><br /><p style="margin: 0px; font-size: 11px; color: #333337; font-family: Verdana; font-weight: bold; display: inline;">Event Date: </p><p style="padding-left: 5px; margin: 0px;" class="smalltext_para">' + data.event_date + '</p><br /><p style="margin: 0px; font-size: 11px; color: #333337; font-family: Verdana; font-weight: bold; display: inline;">Start Time: </p><p style="padding-left: 5px; margin: 0px;" class="smalltext_para">' + data.event_s_time + '</p><br /><p style="margin: 0px; font-size: 11px; color: #333337; font-family: Verdana; font-weight: bold; display: inline;">End Time: </p><p style="padding-left: 5px; margin: 0px;" class="smalltext_para">' + data.event_e_time + '</p><br /></div><div style="float: left; width: 300px; height: 90px; margin-left: 99px; margin-top: 10px;"><h4 style="padding-top: 5px; display: inline; font-size: 11px; color: #333337; font-family: Verdana;">Message:</h4><br/><p style="padding-bottom: 3px; margin: 0px;" class="smalltext_para">' + data.pro_msg + '</p></div></div>',
                '<span style="margin-top: 20px; position: relative; bottom: 0px; right; 0px; float: right;" class="boldheading_smaller" id="readreplytxt_' + msgid + '" onclick="readoffer(' + msgid + ')">Read More...</span>')
                .prependTo("#offer_box_add");
            $("#offer_details_" + msgid).hide();

            $("#offersinfo").html("");
            $("#offersinfo").load("http://www.ahbeta.uni.me/_includes/offers_total.php?usrid=" + usrid);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please post a complete code example.

Comment: I think your ajax response comes as text not as DOM. That's why your onclick event is not working. How are you appending it?

Comment: The whole append is somewhat massive - I think youre right regarding the response coming as text and not as DOM. Is there anyway around this?

Comment: Posted the entire function

Comment: PLease don't use `IE` instead of `i.e.` in a web development question.

Comment: @Musa - I can see the confusion regarding that one. My apologies.

Comment: Are you getting any JS errors in your console?

Comment: @JedWatson - None what so ever, which is the confusing part, even when clicking it no errors are coming up at all.

Comment: I've had a thought - if I used unobtrusive JS that would get round the problem? However, how do I pass the msgid value to the JS

Comment: @Steve_M it might work, and would be better for a number of other reasons also. I just write up an example of how to do it in a closure - i.e. functions can access variables from the scope they were defined in. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, this isn't a limitation of jQuery that I'm aware of.

As you can see in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mbm5a/), onclick event bindings using html attributes work regardless of whether they're in the original source, or dynamically appended in jQuery as you're doing in your example.

It's hard to debug further without seeing the entire page code but it's more likely there's something going wrong with your append logic. Also, put an alert in the onclick attribute (`alert(msgid)` instead of `readoffer(msgid)`) and see if that works - if so there's an issue with the `readoffer` function.

Finally - is there a reason you're not binding the event with jQuery after you append the new HTML? you could use a class to identify the button, and access the msgid via a closure.

Simplified example:

```
function respondoffer(msgid) {
    $('#target')
        .append('<span class="readoffer">read more...</span>')
        .find('.readoffer').click(function() {
            readoffer(msgid);
        });
}
```

Comment: The alert thing was a good idea - It works and displays the correct value, meaning its something within the readoffer function.

Comment: @Steve_M If my answer solved your problem and you've moved on, it would be great if you can mark it as correct (and maybe even upvote if the example answered your question of "However, how do I pass the msgid value to the JS" ;) so that others know. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It can be a scoping issue with jQuery DataTable too. I just had an issue where I something similar to this:

```
<script>
function foo() {
    alert("Squeek");
}

$(function () {
    window.MyDataTable = $('#MyDataTable').dataTable();
    window.MyDataTable.fnAddData(["foo", "<span onclick='foo()'>SQUEEK</span>"]);
});
</script>
```

When clicking the span, foo was never called. If I replaced it with a direct alert, it did work. WEIRD.

It got fixed when I explicity set the window scope for `foo()`:

```
<script>
function foo() {
    alert("Squeek");
}
window.foo = foo;

$(function () {
    window.MyDataTable = $('#MyDataTable').dataTable();
    window.MyDataTable.fnAddData(["foo", "<span onclick='window.foo()'>SQUEEK</span>"]);
});
</script>
```

And then it worked.